# Delete from database from php <select>

Tags: php, mysql, database, product

I am about to make a function so the person i am making a homepage for is able to delete products from a database.

I want it to  be in a select and i have got the products into it. 
But now i need to make the products remove from the database when i check a product in the select list.

```html
<form action="adminremove1.php" method="post">
        
  <h1>Products</h1>
        <select name="product">

<?php 
          include 'include/inc.connect.php';
          $query = "SELECT name FROM products";
          $result =$tilslut->query($query);
          while($out=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
          printf ("<option value='%s'>%s</option>\n", $out['name'], $out['name']);

    } 
?> 
 </select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Fjern produkt">     
</form>
```

How can i make it delete the products? :-)

I hope you can help me!

thanks!

Comment: After submitting the form, run a `DELETE FROM products WHERE name = <from select>` query. Make sure you use prepared statements on that one, as it contains user-input.

Comment: I would query for ID and name. Use the name in the list to show, use the ID as value for the option. Then in adminremove1.php, check for the selected, as mentioned above, and do a delete for the ID.

Comment: OK. So im really new to this. :D 

I've tried the     
$query = "DELETE FROM produkter WHERE navn = <from select>";
But it doesn't remove it from my database.. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @NataschaHedegaard Because the `<from select>` is a placeholder for a variable or a value, a demonstration only. It's not a correct syntax. You need to use `$_POST['product']`, but like I said, use prepared statements on that, which would make the query `DELETE FROM products WHERE name = ?` in `prepare()`, then use `bind_param()` and `execute()`. See the PHP manual for those `mysqli_*` functions.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you please use the product_id in select options values then on the basis of that you can run the delete query on post page of form adminremove1.php

if yoy have unique id for each prodcut then you can use that also
Now if you want to delete multiple products at a time then select tag will be like this

```
<select name="products[]" multiple>
<?php 
          include 'include/inc.connect.php';
          $query = "SELECT product_id, name FROM products";
          $result =$tilslut->query($query);
          while($out=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
          printf ("<option value='%s'>%s</option>\n", $out['product_id'], $out['name']);

    } 
?> 
</select>
```

And in adminremove1.php file you can get value

```
$product_ids =implode(',',$_POST['products']);

 $query = "DELETE FROM products where product_id in ($product_ids)";
```

Comment: Thanks. But how should the delete sentence be after all this? That is my biggest problem. It wont delete from the database..

Comment: $query = "DELETE FROM products where product_id in ($product_ids)";

Comment: If i want to have it so the one who should delete the product can see the product_id also in the select box, how then? :-)

Comment: Right now i can only see the name from the database in the selectbox. Is it possible to get like "16 - Apple" in the select box - the id + the name :)

Comment: yes you have to change the select quey in  $query = "SELECT product_id, name FROM products";